# jquery $(this) not working with coffeescript and backbone

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

$(this) is not working with cofeescript and backbone.Its generating valid code but I don't understand why it was not working. For work around I used $(event.target).

```
Jobmatch.Views.Jobs ||= {}

class Jobmatch.Views.Jobs.JobView extends Backbone.View
template: JST["recommendation/templates/jobs/job"]

initialize: () ->
  @ajs = new Jobmatch.Collections.ApplicantJobsCollection()
  @ajs.reset(@options.applicant_jobs || [])
  @aj = new @ajs.model()
  @index = @options.index || 0

events:
  "click .job_apply" : "apply"

tagName: "tr"

apply: (event)->
   target = $(this) // As this is not working as I expected,So I used below line.
   target = $(event.target) 
   if @options.user_jobmatch_valid
     @ajs.create({job_id: @model.get('id') })
     target.parents("a.job_apply").prev().click();
   else
    target.parents("a.job_apply").next().click();
   false


render: ->
  $(this.el).html(@template(@model.toJSON()))
@
```

And this cofeescript has generated following code:

```
JobView.prototype.apply = function(event) { 
  var target; target = $(this); // not working it is not elementt object
      target =   $(event.target);// this is element object ,working fine    
      target.parents("a.job_apply").prev().click(); 
};
```

Comment: You really should post some example code. It's impossible to know what  `this` refers to in the sentence above without seeing that code in context.

Comment: could you please paste the whole view? i am especially interested in the initialize: function(){}...

Comment: Post whole code of cofeescript..

Comment: Just quietly, is it a good idea to use `apply` as a function name. Because of the native `apply` function?

Comment: that is only class name , although that is string, So no make sense , you can put anything of class name.

Answer (score 2):

In the backbone documentation, http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents 
It states clearly:

> All attached callbacks are bound to the view before being handed off
>   to jQuery, so when the callbacks are invoked, this continues to refer
>   to the view object.

This resolves one of the issues that many object-oriented programmers have with jQuery, that it overrides the context in all its event handlers. As stated earlier you can often use the event, which is passed as the handler's argument. However,  `event.target` can often refer to child elements as opposed to `this`, which always refers to the element selected with the query. For instance:

```
<a href="#"><b>my link</b></a>

$('a').on('click', myfunction); function myfunction(event) {
    this // refers to the "a" element
    event.target // refers to the "b" element 
}
```

In these cases, when attaching mouse events with Backbone to elements with children, use `event.currentTarget` to get a reference to the element that the event handler was attached to.

```
events: { 
  "click a" : "myFunction" }, 
...
function myFunction(event) {
  var $this = $(event.currentTarget);
  // Now, $this is the same as jQuery's $(this)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it all depends on the context,

`this` is in certain cases bound to your view itself, 
take this example:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: { "click a" : "myfunction" },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'myfunction');
    },
    render: function(){
        // rendering data here...
    },
    myfunction: function(e){
        console.log(e.target); // will log the clicked DOM element => <a>
        console.log(this);  // will log the view => myView
    }

});

window.v = new myView({ el : $('#mydiv') });
window.v.render();
```

as you can see, if you should run this example, you can see the differences between `this` and `e.target`. however, this is all due to the keyline in the initialize method.

```
_.bindAll(this, 'methodname', [ methodnames ] );
```

this binds the view to `this` when in 1 of the given methods.
if you would remove `myfunction` from that list,  `console.log(this);` would log the element itself.
but, you would not be able to reach data or functions from your view....
you are free to chose if you bind the view in to `this`.

Comment: So that means I can not use "this" below:
    
     **events:
        "click .job_apply" : "apply"

    apply: (event)->
        target = $(this) //target = $(event.target)**
I am not able to access this here

Comment: this is always available, but you want to have $(this) where `this` refers to the element clicked, if you use the `_bindAll()` like i did, you will not be able to do that, but you can use `$(event.target)` instead... positive point to using it this way, is that you can set or get things from your view, because `this` refers to the view object (as explained in my post) ... meaning you can do  `this.model.set({name: $(event.target).val() });` => you are actually using the view in `this` and the html element trough `$(event.target)`

Comment: Exactly that I was understand as you explained ,but was concern its generated code,in my above code this was generating valid jquery code.for above code it was generating following code :
 `$('job_aaply').click(function(){
    alert($(this)) // It should be jquery object but no luck
})`
So I don't know why that is not working. Although thanks for your help.

Comment: well, i can take a look at your code, if you would be so kind as to post is fully ... either on a jsfiddle or just post the whole view here in your topic. it would help us a lot trying to figure out where your problem is.

Comment: Well 
**`events:
    "click .job_apply" : "apply"
 
  apply: (event)->
 target = $(this) // It should be element object but it was not\n
        target = $(event.target) // So I used this 
 target.parents("a.job_apply").prev().click();`**
\n
and this cofeescript has generated following code:

**`JobView.prototype.apply = function(event) {
      var target;
   target = $(this); // not working it is not elementt object
   \n   target = $(event.target);// this is element object ,working fine
     target.parents("a.job_apply").prev().click();
      
    };`**

Comment: please, just update your original post, it's better with the proper code formatting.

Comment: I have edited original post .By the way thank you for your concentration on my problem.

Comment: "it all depends on the context,". That's completely wrong. As written in Backbone documentation, the `delegateEvents` function of Backbone makes all events specified in the events object literal to have `this` refered to the View object as context. That's a Backbone fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

With events bound through a Backbone view, `this` will be set to the view itself. This is different from normal jQuery where `this` refers to the DOM element

So in a Backbone view:

```
events: { "click a" : "myfunction" },
...
function myfunction(e) {
    this // refers to the view
    e.target // refers to the element
}
```

Whereas in normal jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', myfunction);
...
function myfunction() {
    this // refers to the element
    e.target // also refers to the element
}
```

In both cases, you can use `e.target` to refer to the element

Comment: This is the __very__ right answer and you (author of question) should mark this as accepted, as all the others are containing very unacceptable inaccuracies.